# create interaction term inside SPSS regression formula

Tags: syntax, spss

Is it possible to create a variable inside the syntax for the regression command in SPSS?

example(with positive,negative,psychosu as defined variables):

```
REGRESSION
  /MISSING LISTWISE
  /STATISTICS COEFF OUTS R ANOVA CHANGE
  /CRITERIA=PIN(.05) POUT(.10)
  /NOORIGIN 
  /DEPENDENT intent
  /METHOD=ENTER positive negative psychosu
  /METHOD=ENTER positive negative "positive*negative" psychosu.
```

Comment: Not in `REGRESSION` no. You can do it in other procedures though, such as `GENLIN` (IIRC) - which can of course do regression. If the variables as factors you can use other procedures as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the SPSSINC CREATE DUMMIES extension command (on the Transform menu) to create dummies for categorical variables and interaction terms.  These can then be included in the regression.